# How do I get a program to run automatically after inserting a given device in Windows?

Tags: windows, automation, plug-and-play

I want Windows to dial automatically as soon as I insert my modem via USB, but I realize this is a better, more general, more useful, and more interesting question.

*How can I get Windows to execute a given command once it finishes installing a device with a given hardware ID?*

(I'm guessing this is a Task Scheduler trick. If it is, then great -- this means I can also run the command already elevated.)

Comment: AFAIK Task Scheduler has no event triggers besides time/date.

Comment: The Task Scheduler that came with Vista or later can "perform an action based on an event that has been logged in an event log", and so on. -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). While it is not specifically what you are looking for it can automate all kinds of things on your system. It is a worthwhile investment to learn it.

Comment: AutoHotkey is not applicable, Laurens. Microsoft already provides a command-line executable for dialing connections, called <code>rasphone</code> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555935 . Thanks anyway.